# Send transaction to other wallet

Tags: metamask

I have wallet on metamask and I want to create transaction to other wallet using backend PHP or Node.js is there any API for do that. I want to create code something like that

```
sendTransaction({
 
to: 'WALLET_ID',
from: 'MY_WALLET_ID',
ammount: SOME_AMMOUNT
network: 'NETWORK_URL'
})
```

Comment: Look at Metamask SDK doc

Answer (score 0):

Could you be a little more specific on the use case? I imagine there is a lot of ways to solve this but the answer you are looking for might be limited by the technologies you are willing to use.

For instance, I think you could use web3 on node.js to make a script in which you have all your nodes to different networks and the main account (and private key) from where you are sending tokens. For using metamask you will need a frontend framework. If you would not like to make a big dapp, vue.js could be useful.

The thing that I don't really know how to solve would be the sending of tokens across networks. For that you might need an oracle to convert tokens from a network to another.